# Update elements to show real-time changes in "contentEditable" element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 elements:

```
<h1 class="1" contenteditable="true">ELEMENT</h1>
<h1 class="2">ELEMENT</h1>
<h1 class="3">ELEMENT</h1>
```

Since the element with class "1" has `contenteditable` set to `true`, I need to make sure that they all have the same value and update each other while the content is being edited.

For example, if I were to type in FOO, all the other elements would change to be "FOO".

I tried using some JQuery to do this, but I have had no luck.

```
$(".1").change(function() {
    $(".2").text($(this).val());
    $(".3").text($(this).val());
});
```

Any help would be appreciated as I am still new to JQuery and JS.

Comment: 1. `change` event is not fired for `contenteditable` element. You can use `input` event instead. 2. `<h1>` does not have value in your example - use `$(this).text()` instead. 3. If script is placed before `<h1>`, wrap code with `document.ready`. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3f5rpzhr/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `on('input', function() { })` With few changes in code

> `input` Occurs when the text content of an element is changed through the user interface.

```
$(".1").on('input',function() {
    $(".2").text($(this).text()); // set .text() instead .val()
    $(".3").text($(this).text());// set .text() instead .val()
});
```

However it is not supported in **IE version < 9**

### [**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/2h2a9c23/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It worked perfectly, I just found out there was another question that answered this so it is marked as a duplicate.

Comment: @TheOnlyOneAround Welcome, I wasn't aware of that, Until i see the first comment. :)